# jenkins svn build based on tag checkout - How

Tags: svn, build, tags, jenkins, continuous-integration

We have 3 environments - Development, staging, production

I want have tagged a build - dev1 through svn and I want jenkins to checkout code of dev1. After this when this dev1 is tested n bugs are fixed, i'll tag the build as prod_release_date.
Now here i'll do a build again and push this to production servers.

My question here is - How to make jenkins checkout and build based on tags? when there newer check-ins after the build i want (dev1).

I have partly achieved this using url of that particular tagged build.
(there is a main build n few sub builds and through url based tagged build, it could do the sub builds but it fails during the main build) the error is pasted below.
Any alternatives??? Am i missing something?

> ```
> org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: REPORT /svn/!svn/vcc/default failed
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:379)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:364)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:708)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:335)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.runReport(DAVRepository.java:1289)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.update(DAVRepository.java:831)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doSwitchImpl(SVNUpdateClient16.java:433)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doSwitch(SVNUpdateClient16.java:726)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldSwitch.run(SvnOldSwitch.java:18)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldSwitch.run(SvnOldSwitch.java:8)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:291)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doSwitch(SVNUpdateClient.java:619)
>   at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:161)
>   at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:153)
>   at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:903)
>   at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:884)
>   at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:867)
>   at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:905)
>   at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:878)
>   at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:843)
>   at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:781)
>   at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1382)
>   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
>   at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
>   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
>   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1593)
>   at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:491)
>   at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>   at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
> Caused by: svn: E175002: REPORT /svn/!svn/vcc/default failed
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
>   ... 32 more
> Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/!svn/vcc/default'
> svn: E175002: chunked stream ended unexpectedly
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:754)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
>   ... 31 more
> Caused by: svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on '/svn/!svn/vcc/default'
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
>   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:752)
>   ... 32 more
> ```